# SoapUI, request body in get method?

Tags: rest, request, soapui

I dont see any options i need to put json body in my get request
[image]

Comment: [You shouldn't be sending a GET request with a body.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/8230810)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because GET should not have body by the definition. For GET all parameters should be inside URL (path and querystring) and Headers. If you need to have a body you should use POST or PUT.

Comment: This is not correct. New RFCs 7230-7237 quote "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request". But SOAPUI still don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you a confusing GET and POST.

http://hostname/path?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

This is a GET string. There is no body. All parameters are delivered as a part of the GET string. Everything after "?" are considered parameters, and they are separated by "&" and name-value pairs are separated by "="

If you have a JSON body, that you want to submit, you need to do a POST. Once you have created a REST teststep, which is configured to do a POST, the textbox for editing your body should show up as expected.

Comment: I m not confusing this i only though that i can pass search criteria in request body. But i can do this in request params. Its ok now